# Probability regarding computer science

Tags: probability

Consider the following program segment: 
                                 if B then 
                                        repeat S1 until B1 
                                 else 
                                        repeat S2 until B2

Assume that P(B = true) = p, P(B1= true) = 3/5, and P(B2 = true) = 2/5. Exactly one statement is common to statement groups S1 and S2: Write ("good day"). After many repeated executions of the proceeding program segment, it has been estimated that the probability of printing exactly three "good day" messages is 3/25. Derive the value of p.

Answer (score 0):

To have three "Hello" messages printed you need the following chain of events:

$$(B)\implies\text{Message}\implies(\lnot B1)\implies\text{Message}\implies(\lnot B1)\implies\text{Message}\implies(B1)$$

or:

$$(\lnot B)\implies\text{Message}\implies(\lnot B2)\implies\text{Message}\implies(\lnot B2)\implies\text{Message}\implies(B2)$$

The probability of the first chain of events is:

$$P(B)P(\lnot B_1)^2P(B_1)=p(\frac25)^2\frac35=\frac{12p}{125}$$

The probability of the second chain of events is:

$$P(\lnot B)P(\lnot B_2)^2P(B_2)=(1-p)(\frac35)^2\frac25=\frac{18(1-p)}{125}$$

The total probability is:

$$\frac{12p}{125}+\frac{18(1-p)}{125}=\frac{3}{25}=\frac{15}{125}$$

$${12p}+{18(1-p)}=15$$

$$p=\frac12$$